# Triple Slash Typescript References with 2.0 Libraries

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a project that was originally build on Typescript 1.4

It has a primary file setup like so:

```
/// <reference path="typedefinitions/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typedefinitions/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typedefinitions/moment/moment.d.ts" />
module myApp {
   ...
}
```

Where all other files just reference this main file:

```
/// <reference path="../mainfile.ts" />
module myApp {
   //more code that can reference anything else in myApp
}
```

Part of our build process concats all of our application typescript files together, so we aren't using any module loaders.

In the past this has worked fine, however, more and more libraries have their definition files setup with `import`'s, and referencing them using the above methodology doesn't work.

Taking `ui-router`for example, if I add:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular-ui-router/lib/index.d.ts"  />
```

The types referenced don't seem to appear anywhere.  If I do this:

```
import * as router from 'angular-ui-router';
```

Then all of the other files can no longer reference 'myApp'.

What's my best bet on refactoring my way out of this situation while still being able to compile all TS files down to a single javascript file?

Is there a tsconfig setting I can change?  Or something else I'm missing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I would switch to a module loader that bundles files for you, if possible. It's not worth fighting against what JavaScript is becoming. Remember that single file bundles won't be a good thing once http2 is widely used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

### The recommended approach

These days the option with the least friction is including a bundler to handle your single file needs and using the ES6-style module system to establish dependencies (what used to be known as external modules). The namespace system to my knowledge is not officially deprecated but in my opinion from looking at the community the namespace system has basically been abandoned. It's incompatible with import statements and the @types system, which most of the examples and code you'll see will be using. Following through with this option will require establishing explicit dependencies through imports in each file rather than taking advantage of the C# style namespaces.

You can then use something like systemjs, uglify, browserify, etc. to walk the tree of dependencies and create a javascript bundle. In principle some people prefer this purely to separate out the task of compilation from minification and bundling. This will also resolve some out of order issues you may encounter from using purely namespaces because each file (module) specifies its exact dependencies explicitly.

### Other Options

You can make do with namespaces in the short term by manually downloading the .d.ts file from the DefinitelyTyped repo (or of course using typings, which I would recommend if you follow this route). Several npm packages are now listing @types packages in their dependencies, so you may need to set the `types: []` config property to make sure that nothing from @types is used and so avoid conflicts.

While this is still a workable option, I recommend adopting ES6 modules. This isn't a matter for typescript to decide, the JS community is very clearly moving in that direction and as a superset of JS, major structural JS decisions will trickle down the TS and this will become the default. I feel namespaces will quickly become legacy code, some consider namespaces legacy already.

Comment: My issue is since nothing really references my components (they all reference the main app to register themselves as components, but that's it - nothing references them), they are never loaded by SystemJs: how do I get around that?  Do I need to manually reference each component in a file somewhere to get them registered with angular?

Comment: @John TBH that's how my company does it, but I'm not crazy about it because you have to maintain changes in two places. Personally I prefer inverting it so the components are defined in a vacuum and are imported and registered in the module definition. Neither option is excellent, the latter is closer to the angular 2 approach. I imagine this was done to have a reasonable dependency tree without manually listing all the leaf nodes so it plays nicely with modules.

Comment: @John there may be some way to dynamically load all modules following a certain pattern so the module loader will execute the block even if it's never explicitly included, but I'm not sure if thats a baked in feature at all. You may be able to achieve it yourself by working with the [System.registry keys](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemjsregistry)

Comment: thanks for your help: I just added an answer on how I think I'm going to go about handling the situation

Answer (score 0):

Paarth, I think I'm going to go about handling the issue in a similar way angular 2 does, where I'll register child components in their parent components:

hello.component.ts:

```
import Component from './component.decorator';

@Component('hello', {
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<div>Hi</div>'
})
export default class HelloComponent { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import Component from './component.decorator';
import HelloComponent from './hello.component';

@Component('app', {
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    directives: [HelloComponent],
    template: `<div>
                <div>{{vm.Message}}</div>
                <hello></hello>
               </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    Message: string;

    $onInit() {
        this.Message = 'Hi!!!';
    }
}
```

component.decorator.ts:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import app from './main';

export interface ComponentBridgeOptions extends ng.IComponentOptions {
    directives?: any[];
}

export default function Component(selector: string, options: ComponentBridgeOptions) {
    return (controller: Function) => {
        app.component(selector, angular.extend(options, { controller: controller }));
    }
}
```